# How to use response.body in 401 errorCode in retrofit on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

In my application I want get some data from server and for this I used **retrofit**.
I want show error messages, but after call Api show me force close error.
Because `response.body` is **null**!

My json is :

```
{"data":{},"meta":{"error_message":"\u0644\u0637\u0641\u0627 \u062f\u0648\u0628\u0627\u0631\u0647 \u0648\u0627\u0631\u062f \u0634\u0648\u06cc\u062f","error_type":"OAuthPermissionsException","validation_error":null,"code":401}}
```

**My data model is :**

```
data class ResponseModelRegister(
    @SerializedName("data")
    val `data`: Data = Data(),
    @SerializedName("meta")
    val meta: BaseResponseMeta = BaseResponseMeta()
)
```

**I write below codes for call Api :**

```
override fun callRegister(auth: String, accept: String, contentType: String, body: BodyModelRegister) {
    if (view.checkNetworkConnection()) {
        view.showLoader()
        disposable = ApiClient.getInstance().apisUseCase()
            .getRegisterUser(auth, accept, contentType, body)
            .applyIoScheduler()
            .subscribe({ response ->
                view.hideLoader()
                when (response.code()) {
                    in 200..202 -> {
                        response.body()?.let { itBody ->
                            if (itBody.data.role == STAFF_PROFILE) {
                                view.gotoStaffNextPage()
                            } else if (itBody.data.role == CUSTOMER_PROFILE) {
                                view.gotoCustomerNextPage()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    in 400..499 -> {
                        Log.e("errMessageIS", response.body().toString())
                        response.body()?.meta?.let {
                            view.serverError(it.errorMessage)
                        }
                    }
                    in 500..599 -> {
                        view.responseCodeError()
                    }
                }
            }, { error ->
                view.hideLoader()
                view.responseError(error)
            })
    }
}
```

Logcat message : `E/errMessageIS: null`

Why show me null? how can I access to meta fields when error code is **401** ?

Comment: check if u have something like `errorBody()` instead of `body()`

Comment: @P.Juni in errorBody, how can i access to my meta models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `reponse.errorBody()` instead of `response.body()` to get the error. Also what you can do to make it even better is you can deserialize the Error Body to the known model. Check out this link on how to achieve it: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-simple-error-handling

I see you're using `@SerializedName` so probably you're using GSON, so you can do it easily like this:

```kotlin
data class ErrorResponse(
    @SerializedName("data") val payload: Data,
    @SerializedName("meta") val meta: Meta
)

data class Meta(
    @SerializedName("error_message") val errorMessage: String,
    @SerializedName("error_type") val errorType: String,
    @SerializedName("validation_error") val validationError: ? // don't know the type
    @SerializedName("code") val errorCode: Int
)

val type = object : TypeToken<ErrorResponse>() {}.type
var errorResponse: ErrorResponse? = null
try {
    errorResponse = gson.fromJson(response.errorBody()?.charStream(), type)
} catch(e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}

val errorMessage = errorResponse?.errorMessage
```